# Sets And Sequences Accumulation point proof.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Q:

Show That the closure of S is the union of S and the set of all accumulation points.

Basically i want to make an argument that the set of all the accumulation points is the equal to the $\partial S$

I do have this Theorem:

Suppose $S \subset \mathbb {R^{n}}$ and $x \in \mathbb {R^{n}}$ then x belongs to the closure of S iff there is a sequence of points in S that converges to x.

The Theorem isnt in the form i want it to be to make this arguement

Comment: What is the definition you are using for closure?

Comment: @Daniel $S \cup \partial S$

Comment: and you are using the definition that $dS$ is the set of points such that every ball around them contains points in $S$ and points not in $S$?

Comment: yeah $\forall x \in \partial S $ there does not exist B(r,x) s.t $\forall r>0$ The Ball contains only points in S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** the case that the set of accumulation points of $S$ is precisely $\partial S$. Consider for example the real interval $(0,1)$. Its set of accumulation points is $[0,1],$ but its boundary is just $\{0,1\}$. The boundary *does*, however, contain all accumulation points that aren't in the set.

However, with that Theorem, you're very nearly there. It suffices to show that if $x\notin S$, then $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$ if and only if $x\in\partial S$. Indeed, by definition, since $x\notin S$, the following are equivalent:

> $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$.
>
> There is a sequence of points of $S$ converging to $x$.
>
> $x\in\partial S$.

You should be able to justify each equivalence more or less by definition (using the fact that $x\notin S$).

Comment: I think i may have one trick left . we can abuse the fact that if x is S we are done. and if x is in the closure of S but not S then for each k $\exists $ $B(\frac {1}{k}, x)$ that contains points in S. but this argument is still missing that we do not know if we have all of those points?

Comment: What do you mean by "have all of those points"? Take $x_k\in S\cap B(\frac1k,x)$ for each $k$, so that since $x\notin S$, there is a sequence of points of $S$ distinct from $x$ that converges to $x$, by construction. Thus, $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$. This argument shows that the closure of $S$ is contained in the union of $S$ and its set of accumulation points.For the other direction, suppose that $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$ but not in $S$, so there is a sequence of points of $S$ distinct from $x$ converging to $x$. It follows that $x$ is in $\partial S$ (why?).

Comment: Something do with any neighborhood of x in S converging to x?

Comment: See my updated answer. Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Hmm i think i understand what your getting at ( kind of what i was lost about in my first comment)  if we have a sequence ${x_{k}}$ then every neighborhood of x contains elements in S ie $x_{k}$ so all x are in the closure of S so any x that are not in S but are accumulation points must be in the Boundary of S?

Comment: Why do you know if its an accumulation point of S that it is in the boundary? or are you using the fact that its in the closure but not in S?

Comment: It looks like you've got the forward direction: if $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$ but not in $S$, then since a sequence of points of $S$ converges to $x$ and $x\notin S$, we have that every neighborhood of $x$ contains points of $S$ and points not in $S$. Hence, the accumulation points of $S$ not in $S$ are boundary points of $S$. On the other hand, if $x$ is in the closure of $S$ but not in $S$, then by the theorem, there is a sequence of points of $S$ converging to $x$, which are necessarily distinct from $x$ (since $x\notin S$), so $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$.

Comment: Think its going to take a bit more going over but i will get it eventually. Thank you for all the comments and help!